# Why is Java method overriding not working in the below program

Tags: java

```
class Mammal {
    void eat(Mammal m) {
        System.out.println("Mammal eats food");
    }

}

class Cattle extends Mammal {
    void eat(Cattle c) {
        System.out.println("Cattle eats hay");
    }

}

class Horse extends Cattle {
    void eat(Horse h) {
        System.out.println("Horse eats hay");
    }

}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mammal h = new Horse();
        Cattle c = new Horse();
        System.out.println(h + " " + c);
        h.eat(c);
    }
}
```

In this program I am creating an object for horse but still the output is 
`"Mammal eats food"`.
I want the output to be `"Horse eats hay"`.
So please can someone help me on this.

Comment: It is not method overriding, in method overriding signature of method has to be same

Comment: is it class that you are trying to override?

Comment: Because it is method overloading not overriding.

Comment: Yeah it is not overriding i agree but still i am creating an object for horse then why does Mammal method is getting invoked? i am passing horse object in the method so it should print the method which is defined in Horse class

Comment: Because `Horse` -> `Cattle`  And `Cattle` -> `Mammal`. When you creating object reference of parent class i.e, it is capable of calling respective method. But in your case you are passing `Cattle` object in `Horse` object method  which is not found in horse class and result to calling method of `Mammal` class. I hope you will get this.

Comment: No even if i create Horse object directly i am getting the same answer

Answer (score 2):

To get your required output following code will work:
This is **method overriding**

```
class Mammal{
 void eat(){
 System.out.println("Mammal eats food");
 }

}
class Cattle extends Mammal{
 void eat(){
 System.out.println("Cattle eats hay");
 }

}
class Horse extends Cattle{
 void eat(){
 System.out.println("Horse eats hay");
 }

}
public class Main{


 public static void main(String[] args){
 Mammal h = new Horse();
 Cattle c = new Horse();

 h.eat(); //Horse eats hay
 c.eat(); //Horse eats hay
 }
}
```

Comment: I need the reason how my code is working here i dont want my code to be changed and give the output even i know the same if i change it will work

Comment: Because what you are doing is **method-overloading** and what you are expecting is **method-overriding**

Comment: Yeah it was my typing mistake i agree but tell me the thing which i have asked . I have asked when i am creating Horse object and passing Horse object as parameter why it is invoking Mammal Class this is what i want. Please answer this

Answer (score 2):

Your concept of **Overriding** is not correct, what you essentially done is method **Overloading**.

Overriding only works if the signature of the method being overridden is same. By method signature we mean the **method name** and **parameter**.

So in your code all the child classes should have had the same method signature.

```
void eat(Mammal m) {
     System.out.println("xxx eats food");
}
```

But the important difference between method overriding and method overloading is when they are resolved, for overloading in your case is resolved at compilation time and method overriding is resolved at run time.

So since you used a reference of the parent class to hold the sub-class instance the method of the parent class will always be called as it is determined at compilation time by looking the type of the reference.

To strictly enforce overriding annotate your methods with the `@Override` annotation, if the overriding is not correctly done then it would result in compile time error. In your example if you add `@Override` then you would see the compile time error.

So change your classes to the following and see the difference:

```
class Mammal {
    void eat(Mammal m) {
        System.out.println("Mammal eats food");
    }

}

class Cattle extends Mammal {
    @Override
    void eat(Mammal m) {
        System.out.println("Cattle eats hay");
    }

}

class Horse extends Cattle {
    @Override
    void eat(Mammal m) {
        System.out.println("Horse eats hay");
    }

}
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mammal h = new Horse();
        Cattle c = new Horse();
        System.out.println(h + " " + c);
        h.eat(c);
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
Horse@60addb54 Horse@3f2a3a5
Horse eats hay
```

You might be tempted to think that methods with different signatures are not overloaded as they are in different classes (inheritance) but if you at the [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9):

> If two methods of a class (whether both declared in the same class, or
>   both inherited by a class, or one declared and one inherited) have the
>   same name but signatures that are not override-equivalent, then the
>   method name is said to be overloaded.

it is indeed possible.

Comment: I want the reason how Mammal class is getting invoked when i am creating an object for horse and i am passing horse object in the method hence should invoke Horse class then why does i am getting the result Mammal class method

Comment: I dont want to manipulate my code and give the answer i want what is the wrong in my code so that i am not getting my desired output .

Comment: I want the reason when i am creating an Horse object by default it should invoke Horse class and has i am passing horse object in eat method as your are telling this is method overloding. then why does this code is invoking Mammal class i want answer for that

Comment: I have explained why the method in Mammal class is invoked, it is because you are not overriding but you are overloading. In overloading the method of the reference type is invoked not of the instance it is pointing to.

Comment: *"i am passing horse object in the method hence should invoke Horse class"* you are not doing anything with horse object you are passing.

Comment: The reference type is horse itself you can see in the output it prints the reference of horse not Mammal

Comment: See you are telling it is method overloading then it should invoke the method which is horse class since the reference type is Horse. "It is overloading because it has same method name but different type of parameter" if this is the case then it should invoke horse method since it is overloading. But even this is failing. So this is nethier Overloading nor overriding

Answer (score 0):

The method `eat` in `Horse` does not override the method eat in `Mammal`. This is because the arguments are different.

The eat methods are overloads.

Choosing between overloads takes place at compile time, not runtime. It is not based on the actual class of the object on which the method is invoked, but the compile-time type (how the variable is declared).

Comment: This can be comment not an answer, Please check comments before posting answer like this

Comment: @iamrajshah I think the answer section is available to answer any question, comments are for clarification/queries. And FYI I was writing this answer before pertaining comment was done.

Comment: I am not saying this is invalid, just what you have written is already there in comment so my concern was that only. If you have felt bad then apologise for the same